# How to connect microphone mono to stereo power amp

Tags: microphone, sound, power-amplifier, stereo

I try to connect mono microphone to stereo power amp like this image.

[image]

I connect line of microphone to left and right of power amp input and ground of microphone to ground of power amp but it have no sound. How to fix it?

Comment: The signal from a microphone is generally quite small. Are you using a **microphone amplifier**? What type of microphone are you using? If it is an **electret microphone** (many cheap mics are) then it needs a supply voltage. What model power amplifier? The mono-vs-stereo probably isn't the issue. Using the microphone correctly is.

Comment: There is too little information in your question. If you want to learn from us, invest a little more time of your own. Specify the microphone model, and if you can't figure that out, show a picture. Same for the power amplifier.

Comment: If you have a standard microphone and standard line level input, the standard line level input is not designed to provide DC power (bias) to a standard microphone, so the microphone won't output anything. Do you have a standard mic and standard line input?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a pre-amp first. That power amp will probably require "line level" input, i.e., a signal over 2 volt peek to peek, although you might have a sensitivity knob where you might get the sensitivity lower. But if that picks up a microphone signal is questionable, the voltage level may be too low and impedance not matched. That is why microphones have different inputs on HiFi equipment and stage sound equipment have a sensitivity gain control to deal with guitar pick-ups and microphones. A power-amp is intended to just blast a normalized leveled and mixed signal to full power ear-destroying boom blast levels as desired.

As for mono / stereo, microphone inputs would normally be mono, unless you have two microphones or a "stereo microphone" (which is two microphones in one.) Since you are already having a low level, if you divide it up over 2 channels of a stereo input, you effectively reduce the mic level even more, to half of its already insufficient level.

Of course there are passive and active microphones, the active ones would have a battery inside and they might or might not produce line levels. There are also power amps with sensitivity/gain controls that can be dialed very sensitive. So your mileage may vary and success with one pair of equipment isn't a refutation of the general points made here.